# Read binary structure in R

Tags: r, optimization, binaryfiles

I have a simple binary structure with a few data types that repeats, which I need to efficiently read in **R**. For example, an integer `icount`, followed by a structure `{a integer, b real}` that repeats `icount` times. For example, consider this simple file written by Python:

```
# Python -- this is not my question, it just makes data for my question
from struct import pack
with open('foo.bin', 'wb') as fp:
    icount = 123456
    fp.write(pack('i', icount))
    for i in range(icount):
        fp.write(pack('if', i, i * 100.0))
```

(You can [download this <1 MB file](http://filebin.ca/3E2SWO2QJvHu/foo.bin) if you don't want to generate it.)

To read this file into **R**, I can use [`readBin`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readBin.html) in a for-loop, but it is *painfully* slow (as expected):

```
# R
fp <- file("foo.bin", "rb")
icount <- readBin(fp, "integer", size=4)
df <- data.frame(a=integer(icount), b=numeric(icount))
for (i in seq(icount)) {
    df$a[i] <- readBin(fp, "integer", size=4)
    df$b[i] <- readBin(fp, "numeric", size=4)
}
close(fp)
```

I would like to know of a more efficient method to read a non-uniform binary structure into a `data.frame` structure (or similar). I know that the for-loops should always be avoided, if possible.

Comment: I haven't used it, but `pack::unpack` alleges to be able to unpack a raw vector according to a template.

Comment: Can you share what the data looks like?

Comment: @Tushar you can either generate it or [download it](http://filebin.ca/3E2SWO2QJvHu/foo.bin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fast-running workaround, which is to read the whole block of structure data as "raw", then slice the parts out to interpret the structure. Let me demonstrate:

```
fp <- file("foo.bin", "rb")
icount <- readBin(fp, "integer", size=4)
rec_size = 4 + 4  # int is 4 bytes + float is 4 bytes
raw <- readBin(fp, "raw", n=icount * rec_size)
close(fp)

# Interpret raw bytes using specifically tailored slices for the structure
raw_sel_a <- rep(0:icount, each=4) * rec_size + 1:4
raw_sel_b <- rep(0:icount, each=4) * rec_size + 1:4 + 4
df <- data.frame(
    a = readBin(raw[raw_sel_a], "integer", size=4, n=icount),
    b = readBin(raw[raw_sel_b], "numeric", size=4, n=icount))
```

The tricky part is making the `raw_sel` to slice the relevant parts of the raw structure to read. This is simple for this example, since each data member are 4 bytes. However, I could imagine this being more difficult with complex data structures.

Answer (score 0):

As a note, your loop took (only tested once):

```
   user  system elapsed 
 174.04    1.55  180.96
```

I sped the reading up by using:

```
fp <- file("foo.bin", "rb")
icount <- readBin(fp, "integer", size=4)
df <- data.frame(a=integer(icount), b=numeric(icount))
x=replicate(icount*2,readBin(fp, "integer", size=4))
x=x[0:(icount-1)*2+1]
close(fp)
fp <- file("foo.bin", "rb")
y=replicate(icount*2+1,readBin(fp, "numeric", size=4))
y=y[1:(icount)*2+1]
df$a=x
df$b=y
close(fp)
```

which was faster than I expected at:

```
user  system elapsed 
3.08    0.10    3.18
```